# Sqlalchemy + pymssql connection fails

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I have `freetds.conf` with dbserver connection to database server *(which I am routinely using for PHP)*, the server is on separate server on our own network.

Just to test the connection, I have this small program:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(r"mssql+pymssql://{0}:{1}@dbserver/db_database?charset=utf8".format('user','p@ssw0rd'))

def main():
    print("In main")
    connection=engine.connect()
    print("Connected")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The program prints in main, but never gets to connect. How can I debug this kind of problem and what is causing this?

I have no problems connecting with PHP, so there are no network restrictions and I am running this with Python 3.6.

Comment: You dont have any error ?

Comment: No, it just went quiet, only ctrl-Z killed it. But I managed to find the solution, see below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error after all myself. The problem was that there is an instance on SQL server I am using. Though in freetds.conf there is the instance port mentioned, I also had to add it to the create_engine call.

The working version of create_engine is so:

```
engine = create_engine(r"mssql+pymssql://{0}:{1}@dbserver:12345/db_database?charset=utf8".format('user','p@ssw0rd'))
```

where 12345 is the port number the instance is listening to.

I am sorry that missed that one crucial information bit, but then again, if I had realized it, I probably wouldn't have even asked - and then somebody else might later fight with the same problem.

hank

Comment: yes sqlalchemy use standard port 1433 for mssql if you do not precise it